# Как запустить программу в visual studio code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Выскакивает вот такая ошибка, когда нажимаю Отладка -> Запустить без отладки
Как решить эту проблему?
[image: launch program " doesn't exist]

Comment: Для начала программу следует скомпилировать и получить исполняемый файл, который затем запускать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тэкс) Visual Studio Code для работы с с++ проектами умеет создавать два файла (я точно не помню, происходит ли это автоматически или вручную)
**1. tasks.json**
Этот файл содержит информацию о сборке вашего приложения. Т.е. что должна делать vsc (cisual studio code), когда вы хотите собрать проект.
Пример файла:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "Debug",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                 "-std=c++17"
                , "-D_DEBUG"
                , "-g" 
                , "-o"
                , "<binary_path>"
                , "main.cpp"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Структура файла очень проста, как вы видите в данном случае для сборки будет использован компилятор g++ с аргументами -std=c++17 -D_DEBUG -g -o binary_path main.cpp
**2. launch.json**
Этот файл содержит информацию о том как запускать ваше приложение (например по нажатию Ф5 для дебага)
Пример файла:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "sudo (gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/<binary_path>",
        "args": ["-s", "start"],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [{
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }]
    }]
}
```

В данном случае данный файл описывает как стартануть дебаг для проекта по нажатию Ф5 в редакторе.

Писать с++ный код необходимо непосредственно в .cpp (.c) файлах. Json файлы являются вспомогательными файлами редактора и должны содержать служебную информацию.

Ссылки по теме:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp
https://habr.com/company/microsoft/blog/333680/
https://habr.com/company/microsoft/blog/262523/

Comment: А если мне нужна не работа с целым проектом, а просто с одной короткой программой (аля A+B), все равно необходимо создавать два json-файла?

Comment: @МаксимФалеев, как минимум один файл tasks.json придется создать. VSC это по сути очень навороченный блокнот, если вы хотите добавить функционал сборки - добавляете tasks.json, хотите отладку - добавляете отладку, хотите что-то еще - добавляете что-то еще). т.е. VSC - это пустая болванка, из которой вы можете сделать супер-крутую ИДЕ. Если вы работаете под виндой, то посмотрите в сторону Visual Studio 2017 Community, из коробки - компилятор, отладчик, профайлер и куча всего